# A proof of Bernouilli's inequality

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

One version of Bernouilli's inequality states that

$$(1 + x)^n > 1 + nx $$

for any real number $ x > -1$ with $x \neq 0$ and integer $ n \geq 2$.

I was just reading [this proof](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliInequality.html) on Wolfram Mathworld and had some trouble with a key step for the case of $x < 0$. After defining $y \equiv -x$, the proof starts by writing

$$(1 - y)^n  = 1 - yn + \frac{1}{2}n(n-1)y^2 - \frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(n-2)y^3 + . . .$$

It is then argued that

> Since each power of $y$ multiplies by a number $< 1$ and since the
>   absolute value of the coefficient of each subsequent term is smaller
>   than the last, it follows that the sum of the third order and
>   subsequent terms is a positive number.

Unfortunately, I am having trouble seeing how "the absolute value of the coefficient of each subsequent term is smaller than the last". For if $n$ is sufficiently large, then it seems that the coefficients will initially increase in size (in absolute value).

Am I missing something obvious here? If not, is there a simple way to fix the argument?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't choose to "prove" it that way. I'd forget all that binomial expansion stuff and just do induction on $n$.

Comment: Right I know that it can be proved by induction, but was wondering about the method of proof given above. Can it be made to work?

Comment: "Can it be made to work?" Is it worth the effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $f(x)=(1+x)^n-1-nx,$ where $x>-1$ and $n\geq2$.

Thus, $f'(x)=n(1+x)^{n-1}-n,$ which gives the $x_{min}=0$ and for $x\neq0$ we obtain $f(x)>0.$